# how to read/get message type while using BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, sqlite, broadcastreceiver, android-sqlite, uri

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);

                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
                Cursor d=context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);
                    d.moveToFirst();
                    String  displayName = d.getString(0);
                    String contactName = displayName;
                    d.close();


                Date date = new Date(currentMessage.getTimestampMillis());
                String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date);

                long time=date.getTime();
                String formattedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(time);

                Toast.makeText(context,"senderNum: "+ phoneNumber + ", message: " + message+ " , date:" + formattedDate + ",time: "+formattedTime+ " ,number:"+contactName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
```

How can I read message type? I also want to store this data in sqlite I am new so I don't know how to use sqlite please guide me. thanks

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by message type?

Comment: INBOX, SENT, DRAFT etc?

Comment: yup inbox ,sent etc

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, exactly. If your `BroadcastReceiver` is only handling incoming messages - i.e., it's only handling messages from `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcasts - then those will all be located in the _inbox_ when saved. The system won't deliver it any other type.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I didn't thought about that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to save message in SQLite. Hope this helps you.

**BroadCastRecivier Class**

```
private String contactName = "UnKnown"
private ContactDataSource contactDataSource;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

// Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
contactDataSource = new ContactDataSource(context);
contactDataSource .open();

try {
    if (bundle != null) {
        final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

        for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
            String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
            String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

            Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
            Cursor d=context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);

            if(d.getCount() > 0){
                d.moveToFirst();
                String  displayName = d.getString(0);
                contactName = displayName;
                d.close();
            }

            Date date = new Date(currentMessage.getTimestampMillis());
            String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date);

            long time = date.getTime();
            String formattedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(time);

            contactDataSource.addContact(phoneNumber, contactName, "INBOX", message, formattedDate, formattedTime);

        } // end for loop
    } // bundle is null

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
}

contactDataSource.close();
}
```

**MySQLiteHelper.JAVA**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = ; //database_name.db
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 18;

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(ContactColumn.getCreateTableQry(ContactColumn.TABLE_CONTACT));
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ContactColumn.TABLE_CONTACT);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

**ContactColumn.JAVA**

```
public class ContactColumn {

    public static final String TABLE_CONTACT  = "drivers";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "columnId";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE_NO = "phoneNumber";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME = "contactName";
    public static final String COLUMN_MESSAGE_TYPE = "messageType";
    public static final String COLUMN_MESSAGE_TEXT = "messageText";
    public static final String COLUMN_MESSAGE_DATE = "messageDate";
    public static final String COLUMN_MESSAGE_TIME = "messageTime";



    public static String getCreateTableQry(String tableName) {
        StringBuilder sqlStmt = new StringBuilder();
        sqlStmt.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ");
        sqlStmt.append(tableName);
        sqlStmt.append(" (");
        sqlStmt.append(COLUMN_ID); //0
        sqlStmt.append(" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,");
        sqlStmt.append(COLUMN_PHONE_NO); //1
        sqlStmt.append(" TEXT,");
        sqlStmt.append(COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME); //2
        sqlStmt.append(" TEXT,");
        sqlStmt.append(COLUMN_MESSAGE_TYPE); //3
        sqlStmt.append(" TEXT,");
        sqlStmt.append(COLUMN_MESSAGE_TEXT); //4
        sqlStmt.append(" TEXT,");
        sqlStmt.append(COLUMN_MESSAGE_DATE); //5
        sqlStmt.append(" TEXT,");
        sqlStmt.append(COLUMN_MESSAGE_TIME); //6
        sqlStmt.append(" TEXT");
        sqlStmt.append(" );");
        return sqlStmt.toString();
    }
}
```

**ContactDataSource.JAVA**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class ContactDataSource {

    SQLiteDatabase database;
    MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    public ContactDataSource(Context context){
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    //before any action on database need to open DB
    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    //must close after all transction done.
    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    //add contact to database
    public void addContact(String phoneNumber, String contactName, String messageType, String messageText, String messageDate, String messageTime) {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ContactColumn.COLUMN_PHONE_NO , phoneNumber);
        contentValues.put(ContactColumn.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME , contactName);
        contentValues.put(ContactColumn.COLUMN_MESSAGE_TYPE , messageType);
        contentValues.put(ContactColumn.COLUMN_MESSAGE_TEXT , messageText);
        contentValues.put(ContactColumn.COLUMN_MESSAGE_DATE , messageDate);
        contentValues.put(ContactColumn.COLUMN_MESSAGE_TIME , messageTime);

        database.insert(ContactColumn.TABLE_CONTACT, null, contentValues);
    }

    //get the total count of table ContactColumn.TABLE_CONTACT
    public int getCount(){
        StringBuilder selectQuery = new StringBuilder();
        selectQuery.append("SELECT * FROM ");
        selectQuery.append(ContactColumn.TABLE_CONTACT);
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery.toString(), null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        return count;
    }

    //get all contacts
    public ArrayList<ContactPOJO> getContacts(){

        ArrayList<ContactPOJO> result = new ArrayList<ContactPOJO>();
        StringBuilder selectQuery = new StringBuilder();
        selectQuery.append("SELECT * FROM ");
        selectQuery.append(ContactColumn.TABLE_CONTACT);

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery.toString(), null);
        if(cursor.getCount() != 0){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){

                ContactPOJO pack = new ContactPOJO();
                pack.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(1));
                pack.setContactName(cursor.getString(2));
                pack.setMessageType(cursor.getString(3));
                pack.setMessageText(cursor.getString(4));
                pack.setMessageDate(cursor.getString(5));
                pack.setMessageTime(cursor.getString(6));

                result.add(pack);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    //delete all contact
    public void deleteContacts(){
        database.delete(ContactColumn.TABLE_CONTACT, null, null);
    }
}
```

**ContactPOJO.JAVA**

```
public class ContactPOJO {

    private String phoneNumber;
    private String contactName;
    private String messageType;
    private String messageText;
    private String messageDate;
    private String messageTime;

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public String getMessageType() {
        return messageType;
    }

    public void setMessageType(String messageType) {
        this.messageType = messageType;
    }

    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    public String getMessageDate() {
        return messageDate;
    }

    public void setMessageDate(String messageDate) {
        this.messageDate = messageDate;
    }

    public String getMessageTime() {
        return messageTime;
    }

    public void setMessageTime(String messageTime) {
        this.messageTime = messageTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit what is purpose of ContactDataSource  and why we are using it.

Comment: Its just a separate class, To open/close DB and doing CURD operations, And most important is its maintain Coding standards .

Comment: Hi, VoteUp if it helped. Thanks.